# Android studio says project not gradle-build when importing .aar in a Flutter app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter, aar

I'm trying to import an .aar file
to clear variable, I started a new **Flutter** project in android studio
than I followed the classical procedure:

> file-> new-> new module-> import jar/aar package

after selecting the file I get this message:

> Unable to get Gradle wrapper properties from:
>   C:...\myApp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

Would you like to recreate the wrapper using the latest supported Gradle version?

> Click 'OK' to recreate files, or 'Cancel' to manually set the path of
>   a local Gradle distribution.

I tried both (every time starting a new app)
and later I'm asked to update gradle (to 4.10.1)

at this point I get the error:

> **The project 'myApp' is not a Gradle-based project**

***please not that I don't have any of this problems while importing the same .aar
in to a Kotlin project***

can you help me to figure out how to import this .aar please?
thanks in advance

Francesco

[EDIT] I've tried to import manually the .aar file following this [LINK](https://medium.com/@yushulx/flutter-programming-with-android-aar-file-9f69ca8f98cd)
and when I run it gradle fail to build returning this error

[EDIN N°2] I've used 'api/implementation' instead of compile as suggested by  ''shadowsheep'', the result is the following:

```
      FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\...\myApp\android\build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\...\myApp\android\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\...\myApp\android\build.gradle': 11: expecting '}', found 'project' @ line 11, column 28.
             api/implementation project(':barcodeScannerLibrary')
                                ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
  Command: C:\...\myApp\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
```

Any help?

Comment: `compile` is deprecated I suggest you to use `api/implementation` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations))... anyway if you open the android folder project with android studio you should be able to add the `.aar` file in the usual way.

Comment: First of all thank you for answering me, I've updated the main post

Comment: You're welcome. You need to use only one ^^. Or `api` or `implementation`. But I suggest first to open the android folder project as as an Existing project or by opening a java file and use the Flutter plugin function on the top/right of the file windows (open in Android Studio). After opening as an android project try the graphical way to add your dependency. Btw try posting also your `build.gradle` file and not only the error.